# Webpack doesn't rerun nunjucks after renaming/delete/create new files

Tags: webpack, browser-sync, laravel-mix, html-webpack-plugin, nunjucks

It seems webpack doesn't reload config, when entry point files changes (new/delete/rename .nkj files). I need to rerun webpack to able to generate html file from nunjucks.

If I rename, add new or delete one of the .njk files, I got "Error: Child compilation failed" error.

#### webpack.mix.js

```
const paths = require('./paths'),
      mix = require('laravel-mix'),
      RemoveWebpackPlugin = require('remove-webpack-plugin'),
      nunjucksConfig = require('./nunjucks.config'),
      path = require('path'),
      WebpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');

      require('laravel-mix-copy-watched');

mix
    .browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: paths.base.dir
        }
    });

    mix.webpackConfig({
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                    test: /\.njk$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'simple-nunjucks-loader',
                                options: {
                                    searchPaths: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'templates'),
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            plugins: [
                ...nunjucksConfig.generatePages(path.resolve(__dirname, paths.src.templates))
            ]
        })
```

#### nunjucks.config.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix'),
      path = require('path'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      paths = require('./paths'),
      HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 

const pages = {
    generatePages: function generatePages(pagesPath) {
        return walkDir(pagesPath).map(
            name =>
                new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                    template: `${pagesPath}/${name[1]}${name[0]}.njk`,
                    filename: paths.pages.base + `/${name[1]}${name[0]}.html`,
                    inject: false
                })
        );
    }
};

module.exports = pages;
```

Comment: Not adding an answer as not sure if this will help you, but have you seen this? https://github.com/ogonkov/nunjucks-loader

Comment: Unfortunately no, but thanks. Btw I'm using this loader too.